# Is there a hash function h(M + t1) = c1 that relates to h(M + t2) = c2 in a way that can be verified without knowing M?

Tags: hash, homomorphic-encryption, homomorphic-signatures

Is there a hash function **h(M + t1) = c1** that relates to **h(M + t2) = c2** in a way that, knowing **t1**, **t2**, **c1**, **c2**, and with no knowledge of **M**, it can be verified whether both use the same **M**?

Comment: There exist homomorphic hash functions, e.g., from lattices (look for collision resistant hashing and SIS). For those you have $h(m +t) = h(m) + h(t)$. With that you can extract $h(m)$ and verify that it is the same in both cases.